# Refresh DataGrid after insertion of a record

Tags: datagrid, insert, refresh

I want to refresh my `DataGrid` after insertion of a new record.
I tried binding the `DataGrid` again with new source:

```
dgr_Datagrid.itemsource=tblTable.defaultView
```

but that doesn't seem to help.

Tried `dgr_Datagrid.reload(True)` as well, but failed again. I checked the `ItemSource` of the `DataGrid` after binding and found the new row added into it, but that doesn't seem to reflect in the `DataGrid`.

Is there any way I can reflect the changes in the `DataGrid`??

(I'm using Silverlight 4.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321654/unable-to-refresh-update-data-grid-after-insert-in-silverlight-4

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Void bind()
{
     //Bind Grid Here
}
```

After insertion call `Bind();`

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same thing... I had to explicitly do

```
tblTable.AcceptChanges();
```

A data grid is never actually bound directly to a datatable, but instead, the defaultView OF a datatable.  Since the new record is added to the table, the already bound view doesn't know about it.  To flush the changes of the new record and flush anything attached to the defaultView, you need to do AcceptChanges() to the table.  This rebuilds the bound control.

Now my problem lies in setting focus to the newly created record of the now refreshed grid...

Another option I ran into from other research was to force refresh of the items via...

```
dgr_Datagrid.Items.Refresh()
```